# How do you create a sentential form in a given grammar?

Tags: finite-automata, formal-grammars, compilers, nondeterminism

I am given the following grammar:
$$S ::= aBS| abT |a$$ $$T::= d | dT$$$$B ::= da | ϵ | S$$

I need to decide whether $aBaabda$ can be produced in the given grammar.

I am unsure how the grammar can actually be read. For example, under what circumstances can you read $abT$ in $S$? Can you skip past $aBS$ and go to $abT$ or $a$?

I understand that deciding whether $aBaabda$ can be produced is a theoretical question, so you can theoretically create anything as long as its within the bounds/rules of a language. But I don't *fully* understand the rules of producing a sentential form.

And on not understanding rules fully: can you stop reading input on a *non-terminal*? It's name, of course, implies not. For example, without creating a derivation tree can you tell that something like $aaaabdaaaaBS$ or $aabdaB$ can't be made because it ends in a non-terminal? Except, writing this I realised that a non-terminal such as $B$ has ϵ, so that implies you can end on $B$, right?

Or can you end simply when you have matched a sentential form? For example, if you create a derivation tree and have a node for $S$, do you **have** to carry on reading or can you simply end?

Comment: I suggest reviewing class materials. They should contain a full definition of how words (and sentential forms) are produced in a grammar. Alternatively, take a look at the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Formal_definitions). A grammar produces a sentential form $\alpha$ if $S \Rightarrow^* \alpha$.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But S⇒∗α implies it ends on a terminal, right? If so, that answers one of my questions.

Comment: Wikipedia contains a formal definition of "$S \Rightarrow^* \alpha$". This is all you need to know. You can answer your own questions.

Comment: I am not here to get people to answer my worksheets. All I want to do is have a discussion about things, to learn about it properly. I don't know about you, but asking questions on forums provides way better answers than just trudging through Wikipedia. I have seen that definition before but I don't understand it as much as I would like. Hence why I am here.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to decide whether a word belongs to the language generated by a grammar, then you can extend this to sentential forms, in the following way. For each nonterminal $A$, add a new terminal $\mathbf{A}$. Add rules $A \to \mathbf{A}$. Given a sentential form, replace each nonterminal $A$ with the terminal $\mathbf{A}$. Now ask whether the resulting word belongs to the language generated by the augmented grammar.

As an example, your grammar turns to
\begin{align}
S &\to aBS \mid abT \mid a \mid \mathbf{S} \\
T &\to d \mid dT \mid \mathbf{T} \\
B &\to da \mid \epsilon \mid S \mid \mathbf{B}
\end{align}

The original grammar generates $aBaabda$ iff the augmented grammar generates $a\mathbf{B}aabda$.